# Unable to edit or delete .svc inside Azure.Error 404 not found

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu, svc

I have the following asp.net web application:-

[image]

and using this command, i deploy the web application to azure web app:-

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "PUS"  --name "TDMGroupPUSRER" --src "C:\pus\bin.zip"
```

now when i try to edit the .svc file or delete it i will get "File not found error",as follow:-
[image]

So can anyone advice on this?now inside my web application this file contain this code:-

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ProjectUpdateSystem.RER" CodeBehind="RER.svc.cs" %>
```

Comment: Did you have WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 in your web app setting?  If so, it is mounting zip as readonly virtual file system (files will not be writable).

Comment: Looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2872) for that in kudu github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Kudu's problem and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2872) for that in in Kudu's github repository.

As an alternative you can use either of the following options for file operations:

- Use Azure App Service Editor (Preview)
- Use a workaround in PowerShell or command inside Kudu environment

**Azure App Service Editor (Preview)**

You can find *App Service Editor (Preview)* under the *Development Tools* category of your app service blade or you can add `/dev` at the end of kudu URL. Assuming your application URL is `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/`, then it's App Service Editor URL is:

- `https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/`

Then you will be redirected to App Service Editor. Then you can choose the file from the file explorer at left and edit, rename of delete it.

[image]

**PowerShell**

To edit, not a very beautiful workaround, but working:

1. Kudo → Debug Console → PowerShell
2. Run the command: `Rename-Item sample.svc sample.svc.txt`
3. Edit the file using kudu UI and save changes.
4. Run the command: `Rename-Item sample.svc.txt sample.svc`

To delete:

1. Run the command: `Remove-Item sample.svc`

To create:

1. Run the command: `New-Item sample.svc`

Comment: thanks foer the reply . so my `.svc` is not having any problem, and the issue is that i can not edit it using kudu? but the `.svc` should be hosted and working fine?

Comment: I tried by a svc file having dummy contents. You may want to check if your real svc is working. It should work well.

Comment: @testtest I tested using a real svc file and everything works well. Just created a simple web form application, added a service having a hello function, then deployed on app service. Turned off https only, connected through a client and everything was working well.